# Определение длины построенного маршрута Yandex Mapkit

Tags: java, yandexmapkit

Я построил маршрут между двумя точками, но не могу понять, как мне получить длину этого маршрута с помощью функции Weight. Подскажите пожалуйста. В справке не понял ничего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
route.getMetadata().getWeight().getDistance().getValue();
```